# Basic fragment application is not working

Tags: android, eclipse, android-fragments

I am working on a basic fragment application from the tutorials. All I am doing is adding fragment layout and inflating it. I have attached a class with the fragment as mentioned in the tutorials, but when I run the application, it fails with message "Unfortunately, 'App' has stopped".

Any help would be appreciated.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.fragments"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ArticleFragment"></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <fragment android:name="com.example.fragments.ArticleFragment"
          android:id="@+id/article_fragment"
          android:layout_weight="2"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.Java

```
package com.example.fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends  FragmentActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

ArticleFragment.Java

```
package com.example.fragments;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class ArticleFragment extends Fragment {


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
   return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ArticleFragment in onCreateView you're inflating R.layout.activity_main. That's propably the problem. And delete this entry from Manifest `<activity android:name=".ArticleFragment"></activity>`.